# CUDA: __device__ and __global__ error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "unsigned"/"void""

Tags: c++, cuda, compiler-errors, syntax-error, nsight

So my problem is: I'm using Nvidia's nsight application on mac os x mountain lion to write a CUDA application: The source code is a .h/.cu/.cpp mix.

I have a HelloCUDA.h header with following declarations:

```
//yep, both taken from examples.
__device__ unsigned int bitreverse2(unsigned int number);

__global__ void bitreverse(void *data);
```

and i have a HelloCUDA.cu file that defines these methods:

```
__device__ unsigned int bitreverse3(unsigned int number) {
    //definition
    return number;
}

__global__ void bitreverse4(void *data) {
    //another definition...
    bitreverse3(idata[threadIdx.x]);
}
```

It worked, until I added a new C++ class files (.h/.cpp) using eclipse's (nsight) new class wizard. Now, when I try to build that thing:

```
../src/HelloCUDA.h:21: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‚Äòunsigned‚Äô
../src/HelloCUDA.h:23: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‚Äòvoid‚Äô
```

I checked project settings, I don't think anything has changes.

So, what gives? Anybody could, please, help me with that one?

Comment: What is `idata`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: If HelloCUDA.h is getting included in a .cpp file instead of a .cu file, it won't work.  .cpp files are getting sent to the host compiler, which doesn't know what `__device__` or `__global__` is.  You shouldn't need that header (based on what's posted in this question) in any .cpp files anyway.

Comment: idata is just a part of the code. That's not important, and that's not the problem.

Comment: Robert Crovella, the header is included in both .cu file with definitions, and in main.cpp file where I call these functions. I don't see how I could do it otherwise. Also, I set up project as follows: Project Properties -> General -> Language Mappings -> Language Settings are set as -> C Header file and CPP header file as CUDA C language.

Comment: You cannot include it in main.cpp.  Why do you need it there anyway?  The only thing it provides (based on what you've shown here) is declarations for `__device__` and `__global__` functions which are not callable from .cpp host code.

Comment: Okay, maybe I didn't make myself clear enough... Sorry :(.

The problem is - The project could be built without any problems before I created new class files. I know that I can't call Cuda code directly , and I was going to write wrappers for cuda functions to be called. 

I just wondered, why errors started appearing after I created new .h/.cpp filesm but there were no errors before.

Comment: The errors appeared because you included a header file with device code decorators (`__device__` and `__global__`) in a .cpp file.  The .cpp file by default gets handled directly by the host compiler, which does not know what those decorators mean.  I don't know how I can be any clearer.  Calling wrapper functions would be the way to do it.  And certainly you'll want a header file that has the declarations for those *wrapper* functions, included in both the .cpp file that is *calling* the wrapper function, and the .cu file that is *defining* the wrapper function.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have in NSight Eclipse the problem it shows in the `.h` file for each appearance of `__device__/__global__` syntax error. Everything compiles fine - this is not the problem. How can I "tell" Eclipse that this is a CUDA include file in order NSight will then understand these CUDA specific keywords?

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions above helped me.
Just importing on top of the file:

```c
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
```

Solved it. (I'm under VS Studio2019)

Answer (score 1):

You likely created a new CPP file using "CUDA C Bitreverse Application" template. That template is for CUDA C file. Just delete file contents and add your C++ code instead.